# What is the diffference between these three types of variable declaration in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and i have facing some issue on declaration of the Variables in three ways

[image: These are test cases i have tried]

as my understanding

```
a = "a";
```

and

```
var a = "var a";
```

are (global declaration) same thing

but

```
let a = "let a"
```

is declare as local variable

so as i have tested some combinations

```
let a ="let a"
a ="a"
```

workes

but

```
let a = "let a"
var a = "var a"
```

not works

could you tell me why is that ?

Comment: You can't declare an identifier more than once. (When you don't use `let` or `var`, you're assigning to the global object)

Comment: `var` is function scope, `let` and `const` a block scope declarations. And you can't declare a variable twice in the same scope.

Comment: At the top level of programs and functions, `let`, unlike `var`, **does not create a property on the global object**. See: [let documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

Comment: Don't waste your time with archeology, just make a habit to always use `let` and strict mode and forget about other ways.

Answer (score 0):

`var` is function scope, `let` and `const` a block scope declarations. And you can't declare a variable twice in the same scope (that's not completely true, because you can have two `var a` in the same scope due to backwards compatibility).

So it depends on where you write your last example:

```
function foo() {
  let a = "let a"
  var a = "var a"
}
```

fails because both `let a` and `var a` define the `a` in the same scope.

```
function test() {
  if (true) {
    let a = "let a"
    var a = "var a"
  }
}
```

Would work because they are defined in different scopes, as this would be equal to write:

```
function test() {
  var a
  if (true) {
    let a = "let a"
    a = "var a"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should read up more on different types of variable declarations on javascript from [here](https://dev.to/sarah_chima/var-let-and-const--whats-the-difference-69e). Basically the difference is: 
1. `var` declarations are globally scoped or function/locally scoped. `var` variables can be re-declared and updated.
2. `let` is block scoped. `let` variables can be updated but not re-declared.

So to answer your question:

```
let a ="let a" 
a ="a" // This works as you are reassigning the let variable, not redeclaring it.

let a = "let a";
var a = "a"; // This won't work as you are redeclaring the variable.
```